# Abnormal unresolved external symbol error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, linker

I have a project that used to compile just fine, using the freetype library.

Since then my OS has been reinstalled and therefore so has Visual Studio 2010.

I have re-included and reinstalled all of the .lib .dll and header files. For some reason now if I run the program with the release configuration it runs just fine. But if I switch over to the debug config, it gives me unresolved external symbol errors from the linker, on the freetype library functions.

Now I'm sure my C++ directories for both configurations are identical as I re-set them using the all-configurations tab in the solution settings. As well as this, so are both configurations "additional directories/additional dependancies settings", set identically in the same way.

The only difference I could find between the release and debug folders in the project folder, is the presence of a file in the debug folder called "vc100.idb", which is a minimum rebuild dependancy file. This looked promising, but removing it yielded no results, so I put it back.

Do you have any ideas of what could be causing this difference between the configurations compiling?

Worst come to worst, I can continue programming on the release config, but I'd rather not continue down this road as I'd really like to know the root of this problem.

Thanks in advance,

Guy

The errors:

```
1>freetype.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FT_Glyph_To_Bitmap referenced in function "void __cdecl freetype::make_dlist(struct FT_FaceRec_ *,char,unsigned int,unsigned int *)" (?make_dlist@freetype@@YAXPAUFT_FaceRec_@@DIPAI@Z)
1>freetype.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FT_Get_Glyph referenced in function "void __cdecl freetype::make_dlist(struct FT_FaceRec_ *,char,unsigned int,unsigned int *)" (?make_dlist@freetype@@YAXPAUFT_FaceRec_@@DIPAI@Z)
1>freetype.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FT_Load_Glyph referenced in function "void __cdecl freetype::make_dlist(struct FT_FaceRec_ *,char,unsigned int,unsigned int *)" (?make_dlist@freetype@@YAXPAUFT_FaceRec_@@DIPAI@Z)
1>freetype.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FT_Get_Char_Index referenced in function "void __cdecl freetype::make_dlist(struct FT_FaceRec_ *,char,unsigned int,unsigned int *)" (?make_dlist@freetype@@YAXPAUFT_FaceRec_@@DIPAI@Z)
1>freetype.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FT_Done_FreeType referenced in function "public: void __thiscall freetype::font_data::init(char const *,unsigned int)" (?init@font_data@freetype@@QAEXPBDI@Z)
1>freetype.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FT_Done_Face referenced in function "public: void __thiscall freetype::font_data::init(char const *,unsigned int)" (?init@font_data@freetype@@QAEXPBDI@Z)
1>freetype.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FT_Set_Char_Size referenced in function "public: void __thiscall freetype::font_data::init(char const *,unsigned int)" (?init@font_data@freetype@@QAEXPBDI@Z)
1>freetype.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FT_New_Face referenced in function "public: void __thiscall freetype::font_data::init(char const *,unsigned int)" (?init@font_data@freetype@@QAEXPBDI@Z)
1>freetype.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FT_Init_FreeType referenced in function "public: void __thiscall freetype::font_data::init(char const *,unsigned int)" (?init@font_data@freetype@@QAEXPBDI@Z)
```

**Edit**: OK well this is strange. I've removed **ALL** of the freetype directory information rom the include and library directory setting in the release config, as well as the additional dependancies. And the released config version still works!

This is leading me to believe there is something missing (vs config-wise) from moving my files over.

Comment: The linker settings for the debug configuration are separate from the settings for the release configuration.  So an obvious explanation is that you correctly added the freetype .lib file to the linker's additional dependencies setting for the release configuration but forgot to do so for the debug configuration.

Comment: I explained this above. I set them both at the same time using 'all configurations'. So they're mirrors of each other. 
I think the release configuration is 'stuck' somehow. As the edit to my question explains. I'm currently in the middle of copying the project over to a new, clean project with a new and clean solution file. But so far I'm having trouble getting either configuration linked with the library properly.

Comment: Configurations don't get "stuck".  Check your assumptions by adding the /verbose option in the linker's Command Line settings page.  You'll get a dump of every library it looks at in the Output window.

Comment: @HansPassant I followed your advice, and after scanning through the dump of the libraries involved, I can't find any reference to 'freetype.lib' which is strange, as I have included the folder that houses this file in the libraries directory.

Comment: That's of course not enough.  Read my first comment again.

Comment: Ahhh sorry, I forgot to add to the additional dependancies. I went back and added the directory containing the .lib file to this, unfortunately still no dice.

Comment: @HansPassant Problem solved. Pretty embarrassing. I was treating the additional library directories in the linker general tab as if it were the **additional dependencies** option located in the linker -> input tab (which makes sense really as this is the value that explicitly defines a single .lib file). I must've figured this out last time and forgotten. Because lo and behold, it was defined in the release config and not the debug.....man this is embarrassing. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

I solved it by compiling the  `freetype`( freetype-2.5.2\builds\windows\vc2010\freetype.sln ) solution for the `x64` platform (or `win32` if you use it).

You will get the `.libs` for this platform.